Does there exist a matrix Bernstein type inequality for weakly dependent random variables?
When reviewing the literature, I managed to find the following papers, which deduce Bernstein type inequalities for weakly dependent random variables (where weak dependence is defined in some special sense).
"An exponential inequality under weak dependence": https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-12/issue-2/An-exponential-inequality-under-weak-dependence/10.3150/bj/1145993977.full
"Probability and moment inequalities for sums of weakly dependent random variables, with applications": https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414906001608
However, I was unable to find any that provide a matrix Bernstein inequality, like the kind in Theorem 1.6.1 of Tropp's "n Introduction to
Matrix Concentration Inequalities" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01571).
Currently stuck in my research on bounding the sum of weakly dependent random vectors, so any insight would be deeply, deeply appreciated.
